# Embed URL in QR Code

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

How do I embed an URL in a QR code using Zxing, so that the barcode scanner can detect it as an URL?

I think I need to add something more than just the http://.

Comment: My mistake. There was a space before the URL. Thanks a lot guys. Will up vote all those who answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The most common application of barcodes is to encode the text of URL such as http://google.com/m. To do so, simply encode exactly the text of the URL in the barcode: "http://google.com/m". Include the protocol ("http://", here) to ensure it is recognized as a URL.
>
> Readers should open the URL in the device's web browser when decoding a URL. It is probably desirable for a reader to display the URL and ask the user whether to proceed, so that the user may see the URL before accessing it.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents

Answer (score 2):

Erm, you just write the URL in the QR code. The content is just "http://google.com" or whatever. Any reader will recognize it.

Comment: by providing url (link)  it will create QRCODE of that url m i right ?